How can I generate model from openApi meta
I am working on system which contains tow pages
first one for managing (GET api) services directories
the second : has drop-down list for select service(Which i added in first page)
and a grid below it to browse data from selected API service.
I face a problem how to generate model depend on meta data which I don't know its properties
I tried to build a class which has list of rows objects
each row has list of cells objects
and looping the data depend on Json meta data
and I winder if I am inventing the wheel or there is known solution.
